# Correct usage of code tags

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Suppose there's a piece of code that's just one line long, as the following one.

```
printf("Hello World!\n");
```

Does it make it clearer (more readable) if code tags are used (like above) or is that just plain overkill? So, in other words, which is clearer? Is it better the above, or the following?

printf("Hello World!\n");

My own thoughts are that code tags should *always* be used when code is written—regardless of the length of code—and even if it's a single line. Further, I think it makes things more readable if even a single word that's code-related—like `myfunc()`—is enclosed using code tags. However, I wonder if this is going overboard, and I am interested in knowing what others have to say.

Comment: first one is cleaner and code block make it more readable

Comment: Thank you for your input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code tags should always be used for any code in the post. It makes it cleaner and more readable. IMO it should also be used in the text for indicating a class name or some object. For example.

I am having problem with `SqlBulkCopy` usage with the `SqlTransaction`, following is the sample code....

Comment: Don't forget that using normal code blocks (by indenting four spaces) causes code highlighting to take effect - improving readability.

Comment: Right. This is a great point. Thanks for sharing!